# Bind value from HiddenField asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, hiddenfield

I need to bind the value of a HiddenField control in the .aspx page to pass it along as a parameter for a stored procedure. The value will contain a Session variable value.

For a normal TextBox I do:

`<asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />`

For the HiddenField I would do something in the same way so I can somehow use Bind("UserID") and retrieve the value for it via the Session variable.

How could this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to store the variable in a hidden field if it's already in a session variable.

Please take a look at this article for the correct way to use session state in asp.net:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Comment: But I can't reach the value else where.. The ListView binds the values from the form and saves them in a cs class. If I don't pass the value for the Session variable in the form, I don't know how to reach it.

Comment: A session state is carried over from one page to another and is available in memory without the need for you to store it in a hidden field. You assign it from wherever you are getting it initially - I.e. A database or input field and then just keep accessing it as needed. I can't explain it any better than the link in my answer.

Comment: Yes I know this, but if I cannot access the Session from the cs class. The class is "stand alone" and is only getting values from parameters which are stored in properties. I cannot check for any Session variable in that class, I need to pass the value of the Session variable from the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class to get the needed session value from your class

```
Public Class Sessions

Public Shared Function GetValueOfSession(ByVal SessionName As String)
    If HttpContext.Current.Session(SessionName) Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    Else
        Return HttpContext.Current.Session(SessionName).ToString
    End If
End Function

End Class
```